# Add value found in a line to another line matching a specific field of the first line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Hope you are all doing well!

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have the following lines:

```
2022-10-19 09:12:39.174 WRITING bytes(2566), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(4301), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 Sent bytes (2566) successfully
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(1293), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 Sent bytes (4301) successfully
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 WRITING bytes(7285), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 Sent bytes (1293) successfully
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 WRITING bytes(4289), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:40.123 Sent bytes (7285) successfully
```

I would like to take the value inside the **indexname** parenthesis from lines matching "WRITING" and add it to lines matching "Sent bytes" in the end of the line, ONLY WHEN the number inside **bytes** parenthesis match.

For example, the desired output:

```
2022-10-19 09:12:39.174 WRITING bytes(2566), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(4301), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 Sent bytes (2566) successfully 20220701_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(1293), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 Sent bytes (4301) successfully 20220601_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 WRITING bytes(7285), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 Sent bytes (1293) successfully 20220701_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 WRITING bytes(4289), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:40.123 Sent bytes (7285) successfully 20220601_cfgsys_017507001635
```

I know how to take the 2 values (bytes and indexname) inside the parenthesis:

`cat test.txt | grep "WRITING" | awk -F"[()]" '{print $2" "$4}'`

$2 = the value inside bytes parenthesis
$4 = the value inside indexname parenthesis

however I'm not able to add it to the desired lines
I would need to search on the following lines (after "WRITING") for string "Sent bytes" and $2 equal to $2 of the "Sent bytes" line and ONLY THEN add the $4 to the end of the "Sent bytes" line

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[() ]+" }
($3 == "WRITING") && ($7 == "indexname") { idx[$5] = $8 }
(($3" "$4) == "Sent bytes") && ($5 in idx) { $0 = $0 OFS idx[$5] }
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2022-10-19 09:12:39.174 WRITING bytes(2566), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(4301), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 Sent bytes (2566) successfully 20220701_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(1293), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 Sent bytes (4301) successfully 20220601_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 WRITING bytes(7285), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 Sent bytes (1293) successfully 20220701_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 WRITING bytes(4289), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:40.123 Sent bytes (7285) successfully 20220601_cfgsys_017507001635
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ed Morton! That did exactly the job! I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"[()]" '/indexname/{var=$4}/Sent bytes/{$(NF+1)=var}1' input_file
2022-10-19 09:12:39.174 WRITING bytes(2566), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(4301), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 Sent bytes  2566  successfully 20220601_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.334 WRITING bytes(1293), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 Sent bytes  4301  successfully 20220701_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.398 WRITING bytes(7285), indexname(20220601_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 Sent bytes  1293  successfully 20220601_cfgsys_017507001635
2022-10-19 09:12:39.890 WRITING bytes(4289), indexname(20220701_cfgsys_017507001635)
2022-10-19 09:12:40.123 Sent bytes  7285  successfully 20220701_cfgsys_017507001635
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @HatLess. However here the results are not the expected ones. For 2566 it displays wrong index: 20220601_cfgsys_017507001635, while on the first "WRITING" line with 2566 the index is 20220701_cfgsys_017507001635